# Difference in calling the job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

what is the difference between calling a mapreduce job from `main()` and from `ToolRunner.run()`? When we say that the main class say, `MapReduce extends Configured implements Tool` , what are the additional privileges we get which we do not have if we were to just make a simple run of the job from the main method? Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's no extra privileges, but your command line options get run via the GenericOptionsParser, which will allow you extract certain configuration properties and configure a Configuration object from it:

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/GenericOptionsParser.html

Basically rather that parsing some options yourself (using the index of the argument in the list), you can explicitly configure Configuration properties from the command line:

```
hadoop jar myJar.jar com.Main prop1value prop2value

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("prop1", args[0]);
    conf.set("prop2", args[1]);

    conf.get("prop1"); // will resolve to "prop1Value"
    conf.get("prop2"); // will resolve to "prop2Value"
}
```

Becomes much more condensed with ToolRunner:

```
hadoop jar myJar.jar com.Main -Dprop1=prop1value -Dprop2=prop2value

public int run(String args[]) {
    Configuration conf = getConf();

    conf.get("prop1"); // will resolve to "prop1Value"
    conf.get("prop2"); // will resolve to "prop2Value"
}
```

One final word of warning though: when using the Configuration method getConf(), create your Job object first, then pull its Configuration out - the Job constructor makes a copy of the Configruation object passed in, so if you makes changes to the reference passed in, you job will not see those changes:

```
public int run(String args[]) {
    Configuration conf = getConf();

    conf.set("prop3", "blah");

    Job job = new Job(conf); // job will have a deep copy of conf

    conf.set("prop4", "dummy"); // here we're amending the original conf

    job.getConfiguration().get("prop4"); // will resolve to null
}
```

Comment: Well, that was good explanation with code. I didnt notice few points earlier on like creating Job object first and then getting the configuration of it but it makes sense now..

Answer (score 13):

By using [ToolRunner](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.15.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/ToolRunner.html).run(), any hadoop application can handle [standard command line options](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.15.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/GenericOptionsParser.html#GenericOptions) supported by hadoop. ToolRunner uses [GenericOptionsParser](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.15.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/GenericOptionsParser.html) internally.
In short, the hadoop specific options which are provided command line are parsed and set into the [Configuration](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.15.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html) object of the application. If you simply use main(), this wont happen automatically.

eg. If you say:

```
% hadoop MyHadoopApp -D mapred.reduce.tasks=3
```

Then `ToolRunner.run(new MyHadoopApp(), args)` will automatically set the value parameter `mapred.reduce.tasks` to 3 in the `Configuration` object.

There are NO additional privileges which we we get. Typically people don't use simply main() in hadoop jobs. Using [ToolRunner](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.15.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/ToolRunner.html).run() is a standard practice.